# Cannot remove an unknown active session from my Facebook account

Tags: session-management, facebook

Cannot remove an unknown active session from my Facebook account .  My Facebook account was hacked and I changed my password, then i deleted my active sessions.  There was one session from MI that it will not let me lo

Comment: I _would_ suggest talking to Facebook's customer support... but they don't have a customer support.  File a bug report. They _might_ see it and fix it in a few months.

Comment: Unfortunately no one here is going to be able to help you with this one.  This is an issue that only Facebook will be able to fix or explain.  Sorry...